# How to infer a generic paramater with an async/await function

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I have an async/await function to make sure that the data gets passed along first;

```
func downloadFirebaseData() async -> String {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()    // stop the thread/enter the function
        
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        db.collection("annotations")
            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in        
                defer {
                    group.leave()    // << end on any return
                }    
                if let Lng = i.document.get("lng") as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        annotationLng.append(Lng) //edit the array
                        print("downloadLngServerData ()\(annotationLng)")
                    }
                }
                if let Lat = i.document.get("lat") as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        annotationLat.append(Lat) //edit the array
                        print("downloadLatServerData ()\(annotationLat)")
                    }
                }
            }        
    }
    group.wait() // clear up the thread now, exit the function
}
```

And its called under my view with;

```
.task {
    try await downloadFirebaseData() //error 1 
}
```

```
@State annotationLat: [String] = []
@State annotationLng: [String] = []
```

Inside of firebase database:

```
annotationLat = ["42.828392","29.18273","97.27352"]
annotationLng = ["42.828392","29.18273","97.27352"]
```

I have 2 errors;

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '@Sendable () async throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '@Sendable () async -> Void'

This was under the `.task`

My second error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

This was under `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation`

The first error I somewhat get, but even after I modified from my original code, the error still persisted.

For the second error, I know that I might have to define that this is a string somewhere, because I don't think that the app knows that I'm trying to work with a string.

Comment: Mixing GCD with async/await is not supported you should use one or the other system.

Comment: You should not have any `DispatchQueue`s or `DispatchGroup` mixed with async await. Where are the calls to `continuation`? What is the point of `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation`?

Comment: I suggest (as I mentioned to you many times before) read-up on `asynchronous` functions.
There is also the Swift `async/await` concurency framework that you can use to deal with your 
 `asynchronous` function. And for the benefit of all, read the basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html .
Study and learn first, that's how you will progress, instead of blindly trying again and again something you don't understand.

Comment: I’ve been going back and doing the tutorials that apple had given out, but I wanted to finish this project as I had invested countless hours.

Comment: SwiftX, sorry if I appeared blunt in my comments. You seem to be going from one crisis to the next. And I feel it is because you 
do not have a good grip on some fundamental concepts, such as arrays, and now asynchronous functions.

Comment: No, its fine. I understand your point of view, and that made me realize that I really needed to strengthen my fundamentals. I am still in school, and want to be an iOS dev when I'm older, so having your advice brings me closer to my end goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the Firestore path for the documents is

```
annotations/{id}
```

and that each document has variables `lat` and `lng` of type `String`

[image]

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore
import CoreLocation
//struct to keep the latitude and longitude together, they should not be in separate arrays
struct Annotation: Codable, Identifiable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var lat: String?
    var lng: String?
}
extension Annotation{
    //Safely unwrap the Strings into doubles and then create the coordinate
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        guard let latStr = lat, let lngStr = lng, let latitude = Double(latStr), let longitude = Double(lngStr) else{
            print("Unable to get valid latitude and longitude")
            return nil
        }
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        return coordinate
    }
}
struct CustomFirestoreService{
    let store: Firestore = .firestore()
    init(){}
    func getAnnotations() async throws -> [Annotation]{
        let ANNOTATIONS_PATH = "annotations"
        return try await retrieve(path: ANNOTATIONS_PATH)
    }
    ///retrieves all the documents in the collection at the path
    private func retrieve<FC : Codable>(path: String) async throws -> [FC]{
        //Firebase provided async await.
        let querySnapshot = try await store.collection(path).getDocuments()
        return querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
            do{
                return try document.data(as: FC.self)
            }catch{
                print(error)
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `View`

```
import SwiftUI
struct AnnotationsView: View {
    let service: CustomFirestoreService = CustomFirestoreService()
    @State private var annotations: [Annotation] = []
    var body: some View {
        if annotations.isEmpty{
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .task {
                    do{
                        annotations = try await service.getAnnotations()
                        //Do any other work here, this line won't run unless the annotations are populated.
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
        }else{
            List(annotations){ annotation in
                if let coord = annotation.coordinate{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Latitude = \(coord.latitude)")
                        Text("Longitude = \(coord.longitude)")
                    }
                }else{
                    Text("Invalid Coordinate Value. Check firestore values for document \(annotation.id ?? "no id")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnnotationsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnnotationsView()
    }
}
```

This makes some assumptions but if you paste it into your project you should get some working code.

**You don't need this** for your code but this is what a conversion from the "old" closures to the new `async await` would look like.

```
public func retrieve<FC : Codable>(path: String) async throws -> [FC]{
    typealias MyContinuation = CheckedContinuation<[FC], Error>
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: MyContinuation) in
        store.collection(path)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    //This throws an error
                    continuation.resume(throwing: err)
                } else {
                    let array = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                        try? document.data(as: FC.self)
                    } ?? []
                    //This returns an array
                    continuation.resume(returning: array)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If you aren't calling `continuation` there is no point in returning a continuation of any kind.

Comment: This part works! Thank you so much! I will work on deconstructing it and understanding, as well as watching the videos!

Comment: @SwiftX it will help you to understand it, based on that comment that was in the code in your previous post I know this is an assignment of some kind. If you don’t understand this basic code and replicate it in the rest of you app it will be apparent that someone gave you the answer. That other answer was not of good quality, that is why I put in extra effort this time but having someone write the code for you isn’t the answer, it will be obvious to a programmer just as it was obvious that you are using multiple profiles.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the help. As I stated before, I'm taking the time to relearn SwiftUI to make sure that this does not happen again. Thank you.