# Is Async/Await removed from GoogleSignIn when signing in with the Google provider on Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, gidsignin

I just used the the GoogleSignIn package and have this line in my service file:

```
let user  = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: ApplicationUtility.rootViewController)
```

But when I updated my dependencies, it returns void. When I check the docs I can only find that the line now only returns a completionhandler like before Async/Await. Is Async/Await removed from the package when signing in with google, or is it something in the docs that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't use `GIDSignIn` but if the `async await` version is missing, converting only takes a few lines of code https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Comment: You can find a sample using `Firebase` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429625/how-to-infer-a-generic-paramater-with-an-async-await-function/73430225#73430225)

Comment: I know, I converted it easily. I was just curious.