# Firestore and Swift UI Type of expression is ambiguous

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, codable

It still works but I have not been able to get rid of warning. Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

```
func loadFavorites() {
        CollectionBase.FAVORITES
            .order(by: CollectionFavs.NAME)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    if let error = error {
                        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    return
                }
                self.favorites = documents.compactMap({ docSnapShot -> Favorite? in
                    return try? docSnapShot.data(as: Favorite.self)
                })
            }
    }
```

Here is the model

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Favorite: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    let uid: String
    let name: String
    let street: String
    let cityStateZipCountry: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let phone: String
    let rating: Int
    let type: String
    let comment: String
    let timestamp: Date
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429625/how-to-infer-a-generic-paramater-with-an-async-await-function/73430225#73430225

Comment: That doesn't really answer my questions.  I have several other projects basically same code but older Firebase packages that do not produce the warning/error.  I guess I was seeing if anyone else has experience this and how to resolve.

Comment: You haven't said what line the error is on. Keep in mind, no one can compile this code, so it's important to describe it as much as possible

Comment: My apologies self.favorites = documents.compactMap({ docSnapShot -> Favorite?

Comment: try to include the declaration of `self.favorites`, for example
                 `self.favorites: [Favorite]? = ...` or however you declare `self.favorites`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but added self.favorite: [Favorite]? produces warning on my guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else "Value documents were defined but never used".  Another interesting item is my other projects code completes with data(), data(as:), or data(with:) but this project doesn't have data(as:) but allows me to add manually.

Comment: Although I don't understand `...this project doesn't have data(as:) but allows me to add manually`,
 have you tried: `self.favorites = documents.compactMap{ docSnapShot in
 try? docSnapShot.data(as: Favorite.self) } as [Favorite]?` or some other variations?

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling Firebase packages and reinstalling 3 times I tried removing the caches and that removed the error.