# Async/Await: "out of range error" when trying to access array filled with downloaded images from firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage

I tried to download successfully uploaded images to storage with the code:

```
  func retrieveAllPictures(helloid: String) async {
        //Referenzen zu den Datenbanken
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        //Alle Foto Ids in einem Array speichern
        let result = try? await db.collection("events").document(helloid).getDocument()
        allPictureIDs = (result?.data()!["pictures"] as? [String])!
        var image = UIImage()
        
        
        for path in allPictureIDs {
            let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
            let fileRef = storage.child(path)
            
  
      try? await fileRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    return
                } else {
                    image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.retrievedEventImages.append(image)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

this is how I try to access the array at index 0:

```
struct finalEventView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    var id: String
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
               
                if (viewModel.retrievedEventImages[0] != nil){
                Image(uiImage: viewModel.retrievedEventImages[0]!)
                }
                /*
                ForEach(viewModel.EventImages, id: \.self){ image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 110, height: 110)
                }*/
                Button(action: {
                    Task {
                        try? await viewModel.retrieveAllPictures(helloid: self.id)
                    }
                }, label: {Text("print image arr")})
            }}
        .onAppear{
            Task {
                try? await viewModel.retrieveAllPictures(helloid: self.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when trying to debug the code, I see that retrievedEventImages is filled with the UIImages
still when trying to access the array at index 0 I get an out of range error
maybe someone knows how to fix it, any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you resolve your previous question, the problem description looks similar so the solution might be similar?

Comment: Where’s the code where you access the array?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I did, I tried to save the return of getData in a let and then creating an uiimage with it but then I get other errors  such as "Cannot convert value of type 'StorageDownloadTask' to expected argument type 'Data'" or Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'StorageDownloadTask?'

Comment: @cora I added the code to the question now

Comment: This `EventImages[0]` doesn't exist? Your array is this `var retrievedEventImages`

Comment: @Jay I know, I tried different things out, I changed it bc I recognized it too but the error is still there... I still can't access it

Comment: Well, if you post incomplete code it just leads us to just guessing. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with a complete a minimal example and we may be able to help.

Comment: @Jay I edited the question so now it's right

Comment: Again, `.retrievedEventImages[0]` doesn't exist in your viewModel - it's only within the function `func retrieveAllPictures` and goes out of scope when that function completes. If you want to store them in a var, that var needs to be part of the struct or class, not just within a function. e.g. it needs to be class var. (State object or some other type that can be passed or persisted and won't go out of scope)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't quite get what you mean, could you explain it?

Comment: at the end on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429625/how-to-infer-a-generic-paramater-with-an-async-await-function/73430225#73430225) there is a sample on how to convert and completion hander method to an async await method

Answer (score 1):

**Never access an item of an array in a SwiftUI view rendering area by index**.

In most cases the view is rendered the first time while the array is empty which causes the out of range crash.

This kind of checking for the existence of an item is *unswifty* anyway, just use `first` and Optional Binding

```
if let firstImage = viewModel.retrievedEventImages.first {
   Image(uiImage: firstImage)
}
```

**Edit:** Apparently there is no `async` version of `getData()`. You can adopt `async/await` with a `Continuation`

```
do {
    let data : Data = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        fileRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: data!)
            }
        }
    }
    let image = UIImage(data: data)!
    self.retrievedEventImages.append(image)
} catch {
    print(error)
    // or better show a message to the user
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I changed it and right now it isn't crashing but the picture still doesn't appear...

Comment: `try await` with completion handler is quite likely the wrong API, `async/await` APIs don't have a completion handler.

Comment: do you know how I can change it? I tried to store the data in let imageData = try? await fileRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) without the completion but I can't remove it... I tried to only return if error != nil and then create an imagine with imageData but this didn't work too bc I got other errors regarding the data type

Comment: I tried it with: 

let imageData = try? await fileRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
           if let error = error {
               return
           }}
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            self.retrievedEventImages.append(image)


but then the error "Cannot convert value of type 'StorageDownloadTask?' to expected argument type 'Data'" occurs

Comment: thank you for your help! unfortunately I get the error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" so rn I am trying to solve it

Comment: do you get the error?

Comment: I don't have Firebase. Delete `self` before `fileRef`.

Comment: I did but it still gives me the error

Comment: I looked it up and apparently it needs a return type... somehow still when I change it I get errors

Comment: Try `let data : Data = try await…`

Comment: I solved the problem with: 

   let data = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Data, Error>) in...

Comment: I added (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Data, Error>)

Comment: now it works, thank you so much! I struggled yesterday and today the whole day

Comment: I have one more question, is it safe to loop through the rest of the array with a for each loop?  I wanted to ask since you mentioned that trying to access it might make the app crash

Comment: As long as you don't use literal indexes (an Int in square brackets) there's no problem.

Comment: @vadian I added some await/async code we're using as another possible code solution.

Answer (score 1):

See @vadian answer for an explanation of part of the issue.

To add an await/async code solution as well. I'm doing this on macOS - the iOS solution is similar.

```
Task {
    let resultData = try! await imageRef.data(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024)
    let image = NSImage(data: resultData) //UIImage for iOS
    self.retrievedEventImages.append(image)
}
```

Firebase used the await/async func `data` instead of `getData` to avoid naming collisions.

There's probably more up-to-date info but see [git 8289](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/8289) for further reading.